# Would oracle jet falls into frameworks or library

Tags: oracle, oracle-jet

I wonder if Oracle Jet is a framework or a library? On their website, Oracle said it is a collection of Jquery, JqueryUI and stuff as a library but I saw many people refers to it as framework. So which is correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually more of a Toolkit.  Thus the name, "JavaScript Extension Toolkit".  You can use as little or as much of it as you like.  If you use all of it, it would be similar to other frameworks.  If you only use some of the UI components, they could be considered individual libraries I guess.

In the end, it's a toolkit that you can decide how to make the best use of.